# Saving mobile no in database save filtered no

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, fields

I'm developing a component in which I'm taking the value from a user in the backend using an edit form, but when I type my 10 digit mobile number in the field, it automatically converts it into different a digit.

How can I solve this?

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong in my code:

Tel Field In XML File:

```
<field 
    name="tel" 
    type="text" 
    class="inputbox"
    label="COM_STUDENT_FORM_LBL_STUDENT_TEL"
    description="COM_STUDENT_FORM_DESC_STUDENT_TEL"
    required="true" 
/>
```

Tel field in edit.php (layout file)

```
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="control-label"><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('tel'); ?></div>
    <div class="controls"><?php echo $this->form->getInput('tel'); ?></div>
</div>
```

The `bind` function in the table does not contain the `tel` field for further processing in the Database.

The table Field have given property

```
Name=tel
type=int(11)
default= none
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong in your code, rather your table definition.

Max range of INT in MySQL is:

```
-2147483648 to 2147483647
```

So instead of using INT for your table field, use BIGINT

More details about integer data types can be found here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/integer-types.html